# PHP GetText e strings fora das funções (strings de muito uso)

Tags: php, string, i18n, internacionalização

Existe uma forma de colocar no `.po` strings fora do `_e()`?

Por exemplo, hipoteticamente, 'reais' para 'dólares'. Se em uma página eu citar reais 517 vezes irei traduzir 517 vezes. Ao invés disso pretendo usar `_p('reais')` (hipoteticamente, p de `pegarStringDoArray()`), uma função que encontra dentro de array. Então teria `_e( "Custa 2.43 %s", _p('reais') )`.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Posso traduzir strings que estão fora do `eco()` e se sim como?

Se não fui muito claro posso exemplificar melhor.

Obs: O Google não tem tudo... pesquisa por "*php gettext array of strings*" só retorna comparativos de velocidade... "*php gettext for common used strings*" vira uma bagunça só.

Comment: lendo minha pergunta e para exemplificar melhor, posso alterar_e( "Custa 2.43 %s", _p('reais') ) para _e( "%s: 2.43 %s", _p('Valor', 'reais') )

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Não acho que seja duplicata, é apenas relacionado. A pergunta que você apontou é genérica sobre tradução e localização aplicada a PHP. Já esta daqui é uma dúvida específica sobre a implementação disso.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Mas ao fazer isso, você votou para o fechamento. E se você votou pelo fechamento como duplicata, entendo que é porque você acha que essa pergunta deve ser fechada por ser uma duplicata, afinal é isso que o voto significa. Se você quer que a pergunta permaneça aberta e apenas indicar que há uma outra relacionada, bastaria ter postado um comentário com o link.

Comment: Não entendi bem sua duvida... Pode explicar melhor como está fazendo?

Comment: @PapaCharlie assim: Posso implementar de qualquer maneira, mas imaginei criar um array $gettext= array('Primeira string muito usada', 'Segunda string muito usada')... Para ao invés de usar no eco(), _(), _e()... eu poder a qualquer momento usar $gettext['Primeira string muito usada']...

Comment: @PapaCharlie isso é apenas um exemplo... não pretendo usar dessa maneira. Array no caso seria as strings que uso demais, como por exemplo nome dos meses... Números até 20 por extenso... entendeu... se eu der _('Janeiro') 200 vezes é melhor usar apenas um Janeiro ao invés de traduzir 200 Janeiros

Comment: @PapaCharlie sendo assim, não implementei pois independentemente da  forma como uso... só sai no eco... no sprintf... e pretendo ter variáveis ao invez de usar o eco. Minha função _e() por exemplo detecta automaticamente os %s e outros do sprint, __e() faz o plural... Mas quero um array com strings padrões para usar com %s no _e() e __e().  Acho que dessa vez expliquei um pouco melhor.

Comment: Você podia ter editado a questão com essas informações para ficar mais legível. Está usando algum FW? É o Cake?